# How to have the app check for mobile data ONLY in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-networking

So in this app, it is required to use some sort of network because there's API calls involved. There's an error that pops up when there's no mobile data around. The thing is, it also pops up when I turn the WiFi off, while the mobile data is still on. Is there a way to only have the error message pop up for the mobile data status only and not both the WiFi and mobile data. Here's the code I believe is verifying the network state.

```
public static boolean verifyNetWork(@NonNull Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (cm == null) {
            return false;
        }
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
```

Any help and advice is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you need to add the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission to your app's `AndroidManifest.xml` file in order to use the `ConnectivityManager` class:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

To check for the availability of mobile data in an Android app, you can use the `ConnectivityManager` class provided by the Android framework.

```
public boolean isMobileDataAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected() && activeNetworkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
}
```

You can then call this method in your code and check its return value to determine whether mobile data is available:

```
if (isMobileDataAvailable()) {
    // Mobile data is available
} else {
    // Mobile data is not available
}
```

Yes, the updated code I provided checks for both mobile data and Wi-Fi.

```
public boolean isMobileDataAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected() &&
            (activeNetworkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE ||
             activeNetworkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so basically replacing whatever is inside the `verifyNetWork` method, with the if statement above?

Comment: Yes, you can Replace

Comment: What about for both?

Comment: I have provided another method for both